# jQuery mobile app, multiple page or single page?which will give the closest user experience of native app

Tags: android, iphone, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to develop a jQuery app. It contains about 30 screens.Almost every page uses web service to fetch content from server. Here are my questions.

1.Should I create all pages in single page or should I code them in different pages?
2.What all thing should be kept in mind to avoid page delays and transition problems while      fetching data and navigating? 
3.How can we make the app behave just like a native app?
4.Should i keep it as web page itself or integrate it as native app using phonegap?
5.Should i use jsonp or ajax to fetch data?

Please reply.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Doesn't matter.

2) Do lots of precaching and preloading. Here is a blog posts I did on transitions. I find the 1.0.1 transitions the most native-like.

http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/05/fixing-the-transitions-in-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/

3) Kinda. Web/Hybrid Apps will always aspire to be as good as Native, but almost never better.

4) Depends on your goals. Do you want to sell it or distribute it widely?

5) Depends on the use case...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to create the app and sell it to a client. There is a camera integration module in my project. So i guess that i have to code it as native using phone gap. But my question is if i do so where will the html pages be kept. will it be hosted on server or will it get packaged along with the app.

Comment: They would be packages within the App.